# UPDATE Trigger with condition

Tags: sql-server, trigger, update

I'm trying to trigger an update on a specific user in my user table.
Basically is someone tries to change that user then I want to rollback whatever query was executed and disable the user(using a SP), but if if is not that user, than proceed with the update commit.

This is the code I created:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Users_Trigger_UPDATE]  
ON [dbo].[Users]  
AFTER UPDATE  
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @user_id as nvarchar(30);
DECLARE @action as nvarchar(30) = 'UPDATE';
DECLARE @source as nvarchar(30) = (SELECT client_net_address FROM 
sys.dm_exec_connections WHERE session_id = @@SPID);
    SELECT
      @user_id = inserted.UserID
    FROM
      inserted
   IF @user_id = 'Admin'
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRAN;
        EXEC [dbo].[DisableUser] @user_id, @action, @source;
        PRINT 'Admin User Triggered';
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Other User';
        COMMIT;
    END
END
```

But I'm receiving the error "The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted."

I tried to use the `TRY...CATCH` but the error is the same. I didn't create a nested transaction so I'm assuming that when I use the `ROLLBACK` or `COMMIT` that will apply to the original Query that triggered the `UPDATE`.

I tried an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, but the result is the same.

The result of the trigger is correct, it's doing what I want on the DB side, the problem is that there is software using this table that probably has a `Try...Catch` and as the trigger returns an error, even if the result is correct, the software gives a Login error because the trigger at the end has an error.

Comment: Besides the error issue (which seems like an application issue to me), this part doesn't look right: `SELECT
      @user_id = inserted.UserID
    FROM
      inserted
   IF @user_id = 'Admin'` What will happen if an `UPDATE` tries to update 2 or more rows?

Answer (score 3):

While I am *not* advocating the approach being attempted here (i.e. manipulating the Transaction within the Trigger), I at least wanted to explain what was going on so that there was a clearer understanding of how Triggers work.

Here are some basic behaviors of Triggers:

1. When a Trigger is executed, it is always within a Transaction. Individual DML statements will execute within a system-initiated Transaction (known as auto-commit) if a Transaction was not already active at the time that the DML statement was executed. Meaning:

   - If `@@TRANCOUNT` == 0 before the DML statement, then `@@TRANCOUNT` will be 1 in the Trigger
   - If `@@TRANCOUNT` > 0 before the DML statement, then `@@TRANCOUNT` will be the same value in the Trigger
2. Unlike Stored Procedures where `@@TRANCOUNT` needs to be the same before and after execution, Triggers allow for `@@TRANCOUNT` being higher or lower after their execution, with one exception (see next item).
3. If the Trigger ends with `@@TRANCOUNT` being 0 (before the Trigger exits), then

   1. you will get an error stating that the Transaction ended in the Trigger and that the batch is being aborted
   2. the batch being aborted cannot undo / revert whatever ended the Transaction:

      - If the Transaction was committed, the data will still be committed.
      - If the Transaction was rolled back, those changes are gone.
4. Once the Transaction ends, either by `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`, the `inserted` and `deleted` tables no longer have any rows in them. If you need anything from them after the Transaction ends, then you need to capture it into variables and/or a temp table (or table variable) *before* the Transaction ends.
5. Triggers execute with an implied `XACT_ABORT ON`. This might complicate things, even if you have a `TRY...CATCH` construct. In some cases you might need to explicitly set `XACT_ABORT OFF`

That said, you certainly *can* `COMMIT` / `ROLLBACK` the Transaction within a Trigger. Simplistically, if you do either of those actions, you just need to issue a `BEGIN TRAN;` before the Trigger ends so that you don't get the error about it aborting the batch. This assumes, in the case of `ROLLBACK`, that you want to mask the fact that this happened instead of allowing `ROLLBACK` to cancel the entire operation, which is how it is normally used within Triggers.

However, reality is not so simple:

1. If there are multiple Triggers, the order in which they fire could result in different behavior. Assuming there were no more than 3 Triggers, you can control the order by setting the "first" and "last" Triggers. More than 3 Triggers will likely not be able to control the ordering of all of the Triggers.
2. If there are nested Triggers, then ending the Transaction in the Trigger will could lead to unexptected behavior.
3. If there is an active Transaction before the Trigger executes, then ending the Transaction in the Trigger will take control away from whatever is happening after the Trigger.

To account for the possibility of an active Transaction already existing prior to the Trigger firing, you would need to capture `@@TRANCOUNT` at the top and then issue the correct number of `BEGIN TRAN;`, and possibly also `COMMIT TRAN;`, statements:

```
DECLARE @TranCount INT = @@TRANCOUNT,
        @Index INT = 0;

...

-- For an actual COMMIT, do the following:
WHILE (@Index < @TranCount)
BEGIN;
   COMMIT TRAN;
   SET @Index += 1;
END;

....

-- If either COMMIT or ROLLBACK occurs, do the following:
SET @Index = 0; -- reset in case COMMIT was processed above
WHILE (@Index < @TranCount)
BEGIN;
   BEGIN TRAN;
   SET @Index += 1;
END;
```

Again, *this is **not** recommended* as it changes the nature of any existing Transaction to behave in an unexpected, non-intuitive way. The flow would end up being:

1. Begin Transaction **A**
2. Do something
3. Insert into this Table

   1. Transaction **A** *might* be committed or rolled-back, in which case:

      1. Actions performed as "Do something" above are either committed or rolled-back
      2. Transaction **B** will be started
   2. Transaction **A** *might* be left alone, in which case there is no Transaction **B**
4. After the Trigger exists

   1. If Transaction **A** was committed or rolled-back, it won't be possible to change that action. Transaction **B** will now exist, and changes made at this point will be completely disconnected from changes made previously in Transaction **A**.
   2. If Transaction **A** was left as active:

      1. Actions taken previously are still available to `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`
      2. Actions taken after the Trigger ends are grouped along with actions taken before the Trigger fired as an atomic unit (this is how things usually work and hence the expected behavior).

The definitive reference on all this is [Error and Transaction Handling in SQL Server](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part3.html#Triggers) by Erland Sommarskog.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE USERS(ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(10), ROLE VARCHAR(10), ENABLED INT);
> INSERT INTO USERS VALUES
> (1, 'USER1', 'ADMIN', 1),
> (2, 'USER2', 'USER', 1);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER TRG_INS_OF_UPD ON USERS
> INSTEAD OF UPDATE
> AS
> BEGIN
>
>     IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
>                FROM   inserted
>                WHERE  ROLE = 'ADMIN')
>     BEGIN
>         --ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
>         UPDATE USERS
>         SET    ENABLED=0
>         WHERE  ID IN (SELECT ID FROM inserted WHERE ROLE = 'ADMIN');
>     END
>
>     -- commit other updates
>     UPDATE u
>     SET    ID = i.ID,
>            NAME = i.NAME,
>            ROLE = i.ROLE,
>            ENABLED = i.ENABLED
>     FROM   USERS u
>     JOIN   inserted i
>     ON     i.ID = u.ID
>     WHERE  i.ROLE <> 'ADMIN';
>
> END
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE USERS SET NAME='ME';
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 4 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM USERS;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | NAME  | ROLE  | ENABLED
> -: | :---- | :---- | ------:
>  1 | USER1 | ADMIN |       0
>  2 | ME    | USER  |       1
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=79a1f850859980abf134d457768860ce)*

Answer (score 0):

So the `COMMIT` in the `ELSE` statement was useless, if I don't rollback then as I used the `AFTER UPDATE`, the Update will be executed.

Removing the `COMMIT`, in a normal situation the trigger will not raise any error.